# Laravel 504 gateway timeout -- The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, eloquent

I have a Laravel function which keeps on timing out (The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application). Updating settings on server like php.ini is really not an option for me for various reasons so I'd prefer to avoid that.

This is the function in the controller:

```
public function updateModuleStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $gb = $schem['gb'];
        $gl = $schem['gl'];
        $common = $schem['common'];
        $user = Auth::user()->user_name;
        $glsources = GlSource::all();
        $nlctrl = Nlctrl::where('nlctrl', 0)->first();
        $dtran0 =  Dtran0::where('rec_no', 0)->first();
        $glbtcparam = GLBatchParam::all()->first();
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $current_year = $request->accy;
        $closed_month = $request->accm;
        $next_year = null;
        $next_month = null;
        $new_array = array();
        if ($closed_month == 12) {
            $next_month = 1;
            $next_year = $current_year + 1;

        } else {
            $next_month = $request->accm + 1;
            $next_year = $current_year;
        }

        $account_year = $next_year;
        $account_month = $next_month;
        $module_id = $request->module_id;
        $last_month = $closed_month;
        $last_month_year = $current_year;

        try {
            if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'Y'){
                $countbatches = 0;

            }else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'N'){
                $countbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                        ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                        ->where('batch_status', '001')
                        ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                        ->count();
                
            }
            else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'Y'){
                $countbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                        ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                        ->where('batch_status', '001')
                        ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                        ->count();
                
            }
            else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'N'){
                $countbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                        ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                        ->where('batch_status', ['001','002'])
                        ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                        ->count();
                
            }
            
                    

        if ($request->module_id == 'GL' && $request->status == '002' && $countbatches > 0) {
            $batchyr = $request->accy;
            $batchmnth = $request->accm;

            if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'Y' && $glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'N'){
                $getbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                ->where('batch_status', ['001','002'])
                ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                ->get();

            }else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'N' && $glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'Y'){
                $getbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                ->where('batch_status', '001')
                ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                ->get();
                
            }
            else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'N' && $glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'N'){
                $getbatches = Batch_list::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                ->where('batch_status', ['001','002'])
                ->where('batch_source','!=', 'GB')
                ->get();
                
            }
            else if($glbtcparam->close_period_withopenbatches == 'Y' && $glbtcparam->close_period_withreadytopostbatches == 'Y'){
                $getbatches = 0;
                
            }


            
            $data = Period::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                ->first();

            return view('gl.transactions.unposted_batches', compact('getbatches', 'batchmnth', 'batchyr', 'data'));
        }
                PeriodModule::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                ->where('module_id', $request->module_id)
                ->update([
                    'status' => $request->status,
                    'current_open_period' => $request->curr_open_period,
                ]);

                if ($request->module_id == 'GL') {
                    foreach($glsources as $glsource){
                        if ($glsource->glsubmodule == 'Y') {
                            PeriodModule::where('account_year', $request->accy)
                            ->where('account_month', $request->accm)
                            ->where('module_id', $glsource->source_code)
                            ->update([
                                'status' => $request->status,
                                'current_open_period' => $request->curr_open_period,
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            if ($request->module_id == 'GB' && $request->status == '001') {
                // update gb module
                // $gbmodule = Dtran0::where('rec_no', 0)->update(['account_year' => $request->accy, 'account_month' => $request->accm]);
                $opengbperiod = new Mainparam_gb();
                $opengbperiod->gb_end_month_opn($account_year, $account_month, $last_month, $last_month_year);
            } elseif ($request->module_id == 'GL' && $request->status == '001') {
                // update gl period control
                $gbmodule = Nlctrl::where('nlctrl', 0)->update(['account_year' => $request->accy, 'account_month' => $request->accm]);
            }

            if ($request->status == '002') {
                if ($request->module_id == 'GL') {
                    foreach($glsources as $glsrc){
                        if ($glsrc->glsubmodule == 'Y'){
                            $this->updatePerModule($account_year, $account_month, $glsrc->source_code, $last_month, $last_month_year);
                        }
                    }

                    if ( $current_year ==$nlctrl->account_year && $closed_month == $nlctrl->account_month) {
                        Nlctrl::where('nlctrl', 0)->update(['account_year' => $account_year, 'account_month' => $account_month]);
                    }
                }

                // $this->updatePerModule($account_year, $account_month, $module_id, $last_month, $last_month_year);

                if($request->module_id == 'GB'){
                    $closegbperiod = new Mainparam_gb();
                    $closegbperiod->gb_end_month_cls($account_year, $account_month, $last_month, $last_month_year);
                }
                
            }

            if ($request->status == '001') {
                $periodStatus = 'O';
            } else if ($request->status == '002') {
                $periodStatus = 'C';
            } else {
                $periodStatus = 'L';
            }

            # Historical table for every monthend transaction that is performed.
            $periodHistory = PeriodModuleHistory::create([
                'module_id'     => $request->module_id,
                'account_year'  => $last_month_year,
                'account_month' => $last_month,
                'status'        => $periodStatus,
                'processed_by'  => trim(Auth::user()->user_name),
                'processed_date' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);

            $procedureName = '' . $gl . 'end_month_processing';
                $bindings = [
                    'w_year' => $request->accy,
                    'w_month' => $request->accm,
                    'w_status'=>$request->status,
                    'w_user'=>$user
                ];
                $resp = DB::executeProcedure($procedureName, $bindings);
            DB::commit();
            // all good
            return redirect()->route('toPeriodsdet', ['quarter' => $request->quarter, 'accm' => $request->accm, 'accy' => $request->accy, 'sdate' => $request->pfrom, 'edate' => $request->pto])->with("success", "status updated successfully");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            //dd($e);
            // something went wrong
            return redirect()->route('toPeriodsdet', ['quarter' => $request->quarter, 'accm' => $request->accm, 'accy' => $request->accy, 'sdate' => $request->pfrom, 'edate' => $request->pto])->with("error", "something went wrong!");
        }

    }
```

At first I thought it was a server issue, but all other processes in the system are executing on time.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's taking too long (longer than the loadbalancer timeout is)